# Water Hammer in kitchen faucet

Tags: plumbing, water, faucet, kitchens

I just installed a new sink and faucet and get really bad water hammer when I run the faucet. I never had this trouble before. I made sure the water supplies from the copper to the faucet is as short as possible. How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you looked at [How to fix “water hammer” in your house?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1749/how-to-fix-water-hammer-in-your-house)

Comment: Thank you for your response, yes I have, my problem is localized to a faucet and only happens while water is on, not when it is shut off.

Answer (score 1):

With the water running, and presumably making the noise, put your hands on the copper pipe - can you feel the vibrations?  Does it go away if you hold the pipe?  (Be careful of the hot water pipe - it can get, well, hot)

It could be that the pipe is simply loose.

Answer (score 0):

What you have a 'water whistle' not 'water hammer'. One of the supply valves to your sink isn't fully open, creating a pocket of low pressure behind the valve that is oscillating hammer like effect.  **Fully open your supply valves and the problem should go away.**